Transpose of a matrix_comp
given a matrix of 3*2 A= [[10,20],[74,25],[340,20]] to get output = [[10,30,-10,20],[74,99,49,25],[340,360,320,20]] where the 1st and 2nd col values will be the 1st and 4th col values and 2nd, 3rd col of output will be addition, subtraction of 1st and 2nd col. what will be the solution for this in python?
I tried to transpose

You forgot to post the code you tried, and what specific problem(s) you had with it, as opposed to a very brief description of it.

This has nothing to do with transposition.

Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Point is, you're not even describing a problem, only a task (homework?) and you're not even asking a question. Further, tagging this with both Python 2 and Python 3 makes no sense either.

You can do your particular operation with the following, but I don't know how general you want to be.
As others have commented, "transpose" is a singularly inappropriate description of what you are doing here. (Your original matrix was also 3x2, not 2x3).
import numpy as np
A = np.array( [ [ 10, 20 ], [ 74, 25 ], [ 340, 20 ] ] )
B = np.column_stack( ( A[:,0], ( A[:,0] + A[:,1] ), ( A[:,0] - A[:,1] ), A[:,1] ) )
print( A, '\n\n', B )

Output:
[[ 10  20]
 [ 74  25]
 [340  20]] 

 [[ 10  30 -10  20]
 [ 74  99  49  25]
 [340 360 320  20]]


Thank you for the solution but i want it with a logic which fits  any pattern. let say for same pattern for example  3*3 A=[[[10,20,40],[74,25,60],[340,20,80]] and i should get output = [[10,30,-10,20, 80,-20,40],[74,99,49,25, -45,85,60],[340,360,320,20,100,-60]] - this is a test case 2

Perhaps you would you like to explain more carefully exactly what you want. Your last example doesn’t make sense: it only has 6 elements in the last row, but 7 in all the others. If you want to put the “add/subtract” between every pair of columns then you can easily amend my example to do so.
